# undefined method `stringify_keys' when creating record in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, factory-bot

There is a session variable used in controller for create. How to set the session variable for rspec test?

Here is the method create in controller w/ session[eng_dh] :

```
  def create
    if session[:eng_dh] 

      @category = Category.new(params[:category], :as => :roles_new)    

      if @category.save

        redirect_to categories_path, :notice => 'Category was successfully created.'         
      else
        render :action => "new" 
      end
    else
      redirect_to categories_path, :notice =>"NO access to create category!"
    end
  end
```

Here is the failing rspec code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CategoriesController do
  before(:each) do
    #the following recognizes that there is a before filter without execution of it.
    controller.should_receive(:require_signin)
    controller.should_receive(:require_employee)
  end

  render_views

  describe "Post 'create'" do
    describe "success" do
      before(:each) do
        @category = Factory(:category)
        session[:eng_dh] = true  #THIS LINE CAUSED ERROR ( undefined method `stringify_keys' for "1":String) IN RSPEC TEST!!!
      end

      it "should create a category" do
        lambda do
          post :create, :category => @category
        end.should change(Category, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "should redirect to the category index page" do
        post :create, :category => @category
        response.should redirect_to(categories_path)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set a session variable using that syntax.

The `undefined method 'stringify_keys'` is *not* due to your setting of the session variable, rather it's in the construction of the POST parameters from your `@category` object. The `@category` object has already been saved; `post` expects a hash.

Properly sending the post params will fix it:

```
@category = Factory.attributes_for(:category)
```

Your test began to fail when you added the session line because your controller will only try to save when that session var is in place. Without the session var, `create` does nothing, but your `Factory` line has already saved the row. That's a false "pass".

Comment: just added the initial portion of the spec for categories controller. The error remains after introducing session[:eng_dh] = true. Not sure why.

Comment: Work as charm after adding attributes_for for Factory. Thanks.

Comment: Factory.build creates unsaved object. What's the difference between .build and .attributes_for?

Comment: `build` creates an unsaved object; `attributes_for` creates a `Hash`.

Comment: For let(:admin_user) { Factory(:admin) }
I did
post :create, admin: admin_user.attributes
~Thanks!